# Higher rep, still no posting privs?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

[75 Answers, 15 Questions, 678 reputation.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/587021/a-t)

Can I have posting privileges now?

Comment: What exactly is the the problem?  Have you been question banned?

Comment: What message are you getting that tells you you can't post?

Comment: @Lix: His questions don't look bannable

Comment: @man - hence my first comment... A ban can be enforced for many reasons - not only low quality posts... In addition, as nic♦ will say in a comment below this one - we don't see deleted posts ;)

Comment: @Manishearth - You don't see the  17 deleted, keep this in mind :)

Comment: @Lix I think he's saying he's made an effort, as that FAQ suggests, and he'd like to know if he's done enough now to be reinstated

Comment: @NickCraver: Oh, right. :P

Comment: @Rup Probably not, otherwise that would have happened already.

Comment: @rup - Agreed.  It's still a dupe though...

Comment: I've undeleted a couple of your questions and left comments on ones you need to fix.  Unfortunately, lots of the deleted ones are completely off topic and I'm not sure how they could be fixed.  See if that helps.

Comment: Oh, I deleted them because I found an alternate solution which didn't involve the steps of the question. They are deleted, and most likely too localised for anyone else to find useful.

Comment: I still can't ask questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've removed some of your offending content to offer you another chance.  If you continue to ask "what's the best framework for X?" and other poll type questions, downvotes from the community will re-ban you.

This is a second chance for improvement, please use it wisely.

Comment: Your first meta reversal badge in around the corner ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I am still getting the error: `Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.`

Comment: I still can't ask questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: @AT Clearly you can now ask questions again (I checked your profile for newest questions), so you should consider closing the loop by thanking Nick and Won't and marking this answer as accepted. You ingrate. :-P

Comment: Meh, not sure if community here is rude or just that they handle too much of the same.